# Every time I reference a newly created workbook, Excel creates another

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I'm trying to do what should be very simple. Copy data from one sheet in an existing workbook, create a new workbook, paste that new data there, and then save and close the new workbook. However, every time I reference the new workbook, Excel creates another one. I must be making a very basic mistake.

```
    Dim oldWB, newWB As Workbook
    
    Set oldWB = ActiveWorkbook
    Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
    
    oldWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy
    newWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    newWB.SaveAs "W:\filepath\CopyPasteTest.xlsx"
    newWB.Close
```

Comment: When you run your code, how many new workbooks are created? There should be only one.

Comment: oldWB will be a variant type  not a Workbook.  In VBA you need to specify the type for each individual variable.  Best practice is one dimmed variable per line, optionally followed by an initialiser.  If you haven't done so already install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and have a look at the code inspections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Worksheet.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.copy) without any parameters creates a new workbook.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.copy):

> If you don't specify either *Before* or *After*, Microsoft Excel creates a new workbook that contains the copied Worksheet object.

You want to use [`Range.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy):

```
oldWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy
```